# Why mesh not smooth

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Why mesh not smooth, shade smooth & Auto smooth activated. Still mesh have lines over it. Mesh is divide couple of times and also subsurf level-4 applied. Whats missing or why mesh not smooth. Normals are also in correct direction

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: check the resolution size and try increase and then find the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the curve modifier before the subdivision surface modifier.

[image]

Why:

If done after, the subdivided surface will be shrinked/reduced to the curve resolution.